# Android Support plugin errors after upgrading Android Studio to 3.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I use Kotlin and databinding for my project, after recent upgrade to Android Studio 3.1.0 I constantly see a lot of exceptions in Android Support plugin:

> Could not initialize class android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt    at
>   android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.getTypeName(ModelClass.java:688)
>     at
>   android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.equals(ModelClass.java:694)
>     at
>   android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.findSetter(ModelClass.java:614)
>     at
>   android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.findGetterOrField(ModelClass.java:523)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.lang.databinding.DataBindingXmlReferenceContributor$2.getReferencesByElement(DataBindingXmlReferenceContributor.java:196)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.getReferences(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.mapNotEmptyReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.doGetReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:102)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:59)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:53)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.lang.databinding.DataBindingPsiElement.getReferences(DataBindingPsiElement.java:32)
>     at
>   org.intellij.plugins.intelliLang.references.InjectedReferencesContributor.getInjectedReferences(InjectedReferencesContributor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.intellij.plugins.intelliLang.references.InjectedReferencesInspection$1.visitElement(InjectedReferencesInspection.java:40)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.accept(PsiElementBase.java:274)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.lang.databinding.psi.impl.PsiDbExprImpl.accept(PsiDbExprImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.lang.databinding.psi.impl.PsiDbRefExprImpl.accept(PsiDbRefExprImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.acceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:82)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.createVisitorAndAcceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:70)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.doInspectInjectedPsi(LocalInspectionsPass.java:750)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$inspectInjectedPsi$6(LocalInspectionsPass.java:338)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:133)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.tryToExecAllList(ApplierCompleter.java:223)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:151)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1125)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$wrapInReadActionAndIndicator$1(ApplierCompleter.java:105)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.wrapInReadActionAndIndicator(ApplierCompleter.java:116)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$compute$0(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:143)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:229)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.compute(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecCC(ForkJoinPool.java:1190)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.helpComplete(ForkJoinPool.java:1879)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitJoin(ForkJoinPool.java:2045)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:390)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invoke(ForkJoinPool.java:2616)  at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncherImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncher.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncher.java:57)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.inspectInjectedPsi(LocalInspectionsPass.java:341)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.inspect(LocalInspectionsPass.java:231)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.collectInformationWithProgress(LocalInspectionsPass.java:136)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:83)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:70)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:437)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1130)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:430)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:429)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:405)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:143)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:229)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:403)
>     at
>   com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:170)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

My main **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
    ext.protobuf_version = '3.0.0'
    ext.anko_version='0.10.4'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Application **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

kapt {
    useBuildCache = true
    mapDiagnosticLocations = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':proto')

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'

    // Anko
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    androidTestImplementation 'org.exparity:hamcrest-date:1.1.0'
}
```

And **gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
kotlin.incremental.usePreciseJavaTracking=true
android.enableD8=true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

So far I have tried:

- Invalidate cache and restart
- Reimport project
- Clean and rebuid
- Clean install without former configurations + reimport project + no extra plugins installed
- In gradle.properties commenting out each line by one or all of them + invalidate and restart
- Tried `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"` in gradle "just in case"

Nothing helped and errors still pop up almost in each file. As I can see this somehow is related to binding and kotlin.

Did anyone encounter this issue?

PS

In layout xml files non-existing string resources are not even highlighted, e.g. `@string/non_existing_title` - just appears as a valid string resource (even after clean install).
Though I'm not sure if this issue is related to reported exceptions.

**UPDATE 1**

I noticed that after Invalidate & restart another exception is thrown once:

```
com/squareup/javapoet/TypeName
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/squareup/javapoet/TypeName
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.<clinit>(ext.kt:180)
    at android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.getTypeName(ModelClass.java:688)
    at android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.equals(ModelClass.java:694)
    at android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.findSetter(ModelClass.java:614)
    at android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.findGetterOrField(ModelClass.java:523)
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.javapoet.TypeName PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.3.1] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@19c41e97
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 63 more
```

I've tried to add javapoet dependency but this exception is still thrown once after invalidating. And then only `Could not initialize class android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt` exceptions are thrown as reported initially.

Comment: Issue is not present in Android Studio 3.2 Canary 10
Build #AI-181.2784.17.32.4705630, built on April 6, 2018

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I'll give it a try.
I hoped that this issue would be resolved in recent Android Studio 3.1.1, but still I got the same exceptions in files with databinding.

Comment: Can you navigate from data binding class to XML using CTRL-click? It used to work on 3.0 but now its broken.

Comment: Yes, I can and I can either Ctrl + B to navigate to a definition. But if I type `@string/non_existent_string` then it's not highlighted with red as missing one. But it happens only if xml uses databinding, i.e. root node is <layout>.
In normal xml (without databinding) everything works as expected - missing resources are highlighted in red. So the problem is in databinding processing.
I'll try to upgrade to 3.2 Canary later to check how it goes there.

Comment: Well, Android Studio 3.2 Canary 10 did the trick, but I had to reinstall Kotlin plugin. Thanks, @Yazazzello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hesitations I decided to move to canary channel and installed Android Studio Canary 10 (importing previous settings), and now specifications are:

```
Android Studio 3.2 Canary 10 Build #AI-181.2784.17.32.4705630, built on April 7, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b01 amd64 
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
```

On installing I had multiple issues with kotlin not finding many classes; invalidate and restart, clean/rebuild didn't help.

Then I just uninstalled Kotlin plugin from **Plugins** section and it looks like after restart it was restored with original version and I have no problems since.

Current Kotlin plugin version: **Version: 1.2.31-Studio3.2-1**

And at last everything works as expected. @Yazazzello, thanks for your feedback on Android Studio Canary #10.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad it worked for you. Because I am experiencing issues with databinding on Canary version. Regretting that I hit the button "upgrade Android Studio to 3.1.0."